# Best practices linking data in MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

For an online game, I have a table that contains all the plays, and some information on those plays, like the difficulty setting etc.:

```
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| play-id | user-id | difficulty | timestamp  |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|       1 | abc     | easy       | 1335939007 |
|       2 | def     | medium     | 1354833214 |
|       3 | abc     | easy       | 1354833875 |
|       4 | abc     | medium     | 1354833937 |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
```

In another table, after the game has finished, I store some stats related to that specific game, like the score etc:

```
+---------+----------------+--------+
| play-id |      type      | value  |
+---------+----------------+--------+
|       1 | score          | 201487 |
|       1 | enemies_killed |     17 |
|       1 | gems_found     |      4 |
|       2 | score          | 110248 |
|       2 | enemies_killed |     12 |
|       2 | gems_found     |      7 |
+---------+----------------+--------+
```

Now, I want to make a distribution graph so users can see in what score percentile they are. So I basically want the boundaries of the percentiles.
If it would be on a score level, I could rank the scores and start from there, but it needs to be on a highscore level. So mathematically, I would need to sort all the highscores of users, and then find the percentiles.

I'm in doubt what's the best approach here.

**On one hand**, constructing an array that holds all the highscores seems like a performance heavy thing to do, because it needs to cycle through both tables and match the scores and the users (the first table holds around 10M rows).

**On the other hand**, making a separate table with the highscore of users would make things easier, but it feels like it's against the rules of avoiding data redundancy.

Another approach that came to mind was doing the performance heavy thing once a week and keep the result in a separate table, or doing the performance heavy stuff on only a (statistically relevant) subset of the data.

Or maybe I'm completely missing the point here and should use a completely different database setup?

What's the best practice here?

Comment: Sometimes data redundancy is ok. You need to weigh the cost of computing MAX(score) per user over 10M rows vs the cost of the disk space to store the highscore table and a trigger to update the highscore table when you write a new score.

Comment: Disk space is usually cheaper, but the redundancy comes at a cost of data integrity. You need to ensure that the data in both tables is consistent for all crud operations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Will go for saving the highscores in a separate table.